# ProgressBar does not reset after audio is finished

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, runnable, android-progressbar

My ProgressBar does not reset after audio is done. I ask a question before on this and got it working but now just stopped working and not sure why it doesn't. Any help would be awesome.

All I want is it to chose a audio at random then play one and when finished you can press play again to listen to the same audio it chose at random.

Heres code:

```
 public class player1 extends Activity implements Runnable {


private  MediaPlayer mp;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageButton pauseicon;
private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 3;  //*****REPLACE THIS WITH THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SOUND FILES YOU HAVE*****
private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
private Random rnd = new Random();



   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_1);

        pauseicon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseicon);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        mfile[0] = R.raw.sound01;  //****REPLACE THESE WITH THE PROPER NAMES OF YOUR SOUND FILES
        mfile[1] = R.raw.sound02;  //PLACE THE SOUND FILES IN THE /res/raw/ FOLDER IN YOUR PROJECT*****
        mfile[2] = R.raw.sound03;
        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */


        try{
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(player1.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
             mp.seekTo(0);
             mp.start(); ;         
             progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
             progressBar.setProgress(0);
             progressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
             new Thread(this).start();


         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            //When audio is done will change pause to play
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pauseicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);

            }
        });


        pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 // No need to check if it is pauseicon

        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
         ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);

        } else {
            mp.start();
            ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);
     }}});

   }
        //To update progress bar
   public void run() {
        int currentPosition= 0;
        int total = mp.getDuration();
        while (mp!=null && currentPosition<=total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }            
            progressBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
    }
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);


        if (mp != null)
        if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
     }
    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
      if (mp != null){
          if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();
      }

      //there is no reason to call super.finish(); here
      //call super.onBackPressed(); and it will finish that activity for you
      super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Just adding `progressBar.setProgress(0);` to `public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)` is enough.

Comment: This works but then the progress bar does not move when you want to play it again. Thanks but did not work

Answer (score 1):

You problem is `mp.getDuration()` is a milliseconds, which changes in each song. So don't use `progressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());`. As it only works once for the very first song. Use `progressBar.setMax(100);` instead. Then use `currentPosition= 100 * mp.getCurrentPosition() / mp.getDuration();` This should work fine.

Also don't forget adding `progressBar.setProgress(0);` when one song is finished or stop-button is clicked.

Comment: This just put the bar to the max as soon as the audio starts. Also to add I don't want it to play a new audio after the audio is done. All I want is it chose a audio at random then plays one and when finished you can press play again to listen to the same audio it chose at random.

Comment: You are still using your codes if it just put the bar to the max as soon as the audio starts. As your codes use a millisecond which is far more than the setMax(100). In my codes, I use `currentPosition= 100 * mp.getCurrentPosition() / mp.getDuration();`, which is a 100*percentage, that should not lead what you say.

Comment: Could you show me the example of what I need to do in case i'm doing it wrong. Sorry for being a bit of a noob

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try resetting it inside of your completion listener. Scratch the setter then. Try using this:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
currentPosition++;
```

Instead of this:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
```

That is in your `run()` function. Then it will increment from 0 to total and you won't have to worry about getting or setting the currentposition, just the progress which is being done with the previous change below.

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    //When audio is done will change pause to play       
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        pauseicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);

        //Reset here
        progressBar.setProgress(0);  
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this but it reset the bar but then the pause does not change to play when finished and if you press it, it plays the audio but the bar does not move. Thanks for your help but does not work

Comment: I've also tried this but It works but then the progress bar does not move when you want to play it again. Thanks but did not work

Comment: You may also need to reset `currentPosition` using the setter that you have with `.getCurrentPosition()` inside your run function. I added it to my answer above.

Comment: I get an error under setCurrentPosition saying The method setCurrentPosition(int) is undefined for the type ProgressBar any help?

Comment: Where you have your `.getCurrentPosition()` function defined, you need to also define a setter. I'll add it to my answer above.

Comment: Where would them two lines go? Sorry for being a bit of a noob

Comment: They should be in your ProgressBar class. The `getCurrentPosition()` should already be there since you are currently using it.

Comment: I don't have a ProgressBar class just the player 1

Comment: Try the edit above, if that doesn't work then I'll be surprised.

Comment: The bar move one little dot on the bar at the beginning then does not move and when it's finished it still stays there.

Comment: I am out of ideas. There is no reason that shouldn't work from what I can see. Either your while loop is ending due to total not being set correctly, mp is becoming null or it is encountering an exception and returning.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36345/discussion-between-user2407147-and-chad)